QTreeView with reorderable elements, but elements should nstay in the same parent folder
i am using PyQt6.
I want to have a QTreeview with reorderable Elements.
But the elements shuld only be moved in the same hierarchy deep than it was, like in this picture, Item 'A1' should only be reordered in Folder 'AAA'

As I thought, I can implement over the dragMoveEvent, that when the cursor shows me the 'place into' tooltip, I can cancel the operation - but I did not find the correcponding value to fetch the cursor.
Does anyone have a same problem.
Here is the code:
class TreeViewWithReorder(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Tree View with Reorderable Functionality")
        self.resize(600, 400)

        # Create a QStandardItemModel
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        # Create a root item
        root_item = QStandardItem('AAA')
        root_item_2 = QStandardItem('BBB')

        # Create child items
        technician1 = QStandardItem('A1')
        technician2 = QStandardItem('A2')
        technician3 = QStandardItem('A3')

        technician4 = QStandardItem('B1')
        technician5 = QStandardItem('B2')

        # Add child items to the root items
        root_item.appendRow(technician1)
        root_item.appendRow(technician2)
        root_item.appendRow(technician3)

        root_item_2.appendRow(technician4)
        root_item_2.appendRow(technician5)

        # Set the model's root items
        self.model.appendRow(root_item)
        self.model.appendRow(root_item_2)

        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QTreeView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().dragMoveEvent(event)

EDIT:
Problem of the child that becomes a new parent:


You need to check if the possible target of the drop event is the same parent of the dragged item.
One possibility would be the following:
    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() != self:
            event.ignore()
            return
        super().dragMoveEvent(event)
        index = self.selectedIndexes()[0]
        target = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if index.parent() == target or not event.isAccepted():
            return
        elif (
            target.parent() != index.parent()
            or self.dropIndicatorPosition() == self.DropIndicatorPosition.OnItem
        ):
            event.ignore()

The procedure is the following:

get the currently selected item, which assumes that it's the item that is being dragged;
get the model index under the mouse, which is where it would eventually be dropped;
call the base implementation, which would eventually accept or reject the event;
if the target is the parent, we go on with the default behavior;
if the target parent is the same of the dragged index, it means that we're dropping within the same parent, but we need to ensure that we're not trying to drop on a child item; if none of the above checks out, we ignore the event, so drop won't be possible;

Note that you should always ensure that items have the correct drag/drop flags. For instance, the root items should not be draggable, and the child items should probably not allow dropping on them, otherwise they would become parents as well.
In your case, and for basic one-level structures, you could do the following in the __init__:
        for pr in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            parent = self.model.item(pr)
            parent.setFlags(parent.flags() & ~Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDragEnabled)
            for cr in range(parent.rowCount()):
                child = parent.child(cr)
                child.setFlags(child.flags() & ~Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled)

        root = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        root.setFlags(root.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)

The last line is similar to what done for child items, but prevents dropping anything on the root index.
If your structure has more than one level, then you should eventually change the above flags only for items that can have children, and therefore you also need to check that within the dragMoveEvent() above.

Thank you, but there is still a problem: I can drag a child item to the parents root, so when i drag a children out, i get a new parent

I added a gif to my question
